# Will creating virtual host, disrupt regular routing

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, laravel

I am making my first foray into laravel development . I am coming from a codeigniter background. The official tutorial http://daylerees.com/2012/03/25/laravel-getting-started/ advises starting by setting up a virtual host, which I have never done. I have a number of projects that I develop in the easyphp wamp, along with netbeans, and I am concerned about how to set up a virtual host without affecting the routing of my other projects. is there a way to make the virtual host conditional on if my laravel test project is running and otherwise default to the standard settings for the other projects?

Thank you,

Bill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A virtual host is only needed if you want to host several sites on the same IP address. 
As I read your post, you already have setup an environment where you can develop php apps.

Just continue on that path and you will be fine.

Comment: I would like to mention another case in which I was developing a website in need of making payment transactions via a payment gateway and the callback from the bank started working correctly only after running laravel under a virtual host.

Answer (score 1):

Adding virtual hosts most likely wont change anything to your current projects` paths. Try to do that and when some problems occurs ill try to help.